# How to commit and rollback transaction in parse cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to insert an object in multiple table class, if error happens while inserting in any one of the class how to rollback to previous state like Begin, Commit and Rollback transation in MySQL server

Answer (score 2):

**Parse** does not have roll-back feature based on their post:https://www.parse.com/questions/saveall-and-rollback--2

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do transactions like in MySQL Server or as if you where having a unit of work in Entity Framework.

Best option I can think about is to use the [promise pattern](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises). With promises, your code can be much cleaner than the nested code you get with callbacks. This way you can deal with the erro handeling cases nicely but still not the same as transactions.

Comment: Using promise pattern query can be executed step by step, but if an error occurs is there any rollback class available to undo previous executed querys

Comment: Not that I am aware of. What you can also want to check, totally beside the promise pattern, is to perfom actions after a save. https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave this way you only get to the next save if the previous one worked, I actually do somethign similar in my cloud code.